# Xamarin MVVM : Work with just one JSON Folder to change language

Tags: android, ios, xamarin, internationalization, mvvmcross

I want to know if we can create just one Localization folder for my application in MVVMCross (Android, IOS, Core) to change the language.

In fact, i watching this video/tuto to change my Application Language with MVVMCross: https://youtu.be/VkxHtbJ_Tlk

I downloaded the sample too and i can see, his folder BabelResources is in his Android project, in his IOS Projet, in WPF etc...

I can't create just one ressource folder and create just one JSON file with my translation (In my PCL for example)

Thank for your help

Comment: Hey, i work only with Resx, it's most simply because with Json file you need to create each json for each project. With resx you can work with your PCL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://opendix.blogspot.dk/2013/05/using-resx-files-for-localization-in.html

or`

http://enginecore.blogspot.dk/2013/09/localization-in-xamarin-mvvmcross_18.html

or

http://blog.giovannimodica.com/post/internationalization-of-a-cross-platform-application

Hope one of them can help you on your way :) Alternatively, you could add the translation file in for example the android project and add it as link in the ios project.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an alternative using simple text files in your PCL: https://github.com/xleon/I18N-Portable

Answer (score 0):

The video tutorial you're referring to is using linked files in other projects. So you setup up only one resource file and use it in all the platform projects by linking to the file (instead of copying it)

You can find the source here: https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross-Tutorials/tree/master/Babel